# Jacobian vs Gradient in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[According to the wikipedia definition of Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), if $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$, then $Jf=\nabla f^{T}$, where $Jf$ is the jacobian of $f$ and $\nabla f$ is its gradient. Note: I simply took the special case $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}, m=1$

However, in polar coordinates, we know the gradient of a function $f(r,\theta)$ is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial r } (r,\theta) \\\\
\frac{1}{r}\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial \theta }(r,\theta) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
while the Jacobian, which does not depend on the coordinate system, should still be:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial r } (r,\theta) , \quad
\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial \theta }(r,\theta) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So its off by the factor $\frac{1}{r}$. Am I wrong somewhere, if not how can we explain this?

Comment: Not really, as your link does not mention Jacobians. It talks about holonomic basis, which according to wikipedia are related to manifolds, which I am not familiar with.

Comment: The link precisely goes to the bottom of why in some conventions there is the factor $\frac1r$ and in some there is not. Where did I mention manifolds? The duplicate is self contained. In short: the Jacobian is usually a bunch of partial derivatives. The gradient in the coordinate basis is the same. Physicists like the orthonormal basis. That's why they normalize by $\frac1r\,.$